# Send File Via Bluetooth from pc to Mobile With C#

Tags: c#, bluetooth

Hi im new to blutooth development environment in C#.Net
Actually my project is a C# application which should automatically search bluetooth Mobiles via my pc 's blutooth device and send a specific file to the searched mobiles automatically.
Note:The search should update every 2 Minutes including Manual device search strategies !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My library [32feet.NET](http://32feet.codeplex.com/) should be useful...

Device Discovery can be done with BluetoothClient.DiscoverDevices, and sending a file should normally be done with ObexWebRequest, see the [User Guide](http://www.alanjmcf.me.uk/comms/bluetooth/32feet.NET%20--%20User%20Guide.html) for more info.